# NService Bus - Get all Pending Messages on a Queue

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I have an application which receives data from a number of other applications via WCF.

I now have customers which would also like to receive copies of that data, but different customers have different needs.

- Customer A would like for us to call a web service to send him data
- Customer B would like for us to Email him with the data
- Customer C would like to set up his own system which will poll a web service that I provide to receive his data.

I've been wanting to use NServiceBus for quite a while, and it seems like this is a good application.  I think I can handle Customer A and B just fine by setting up endpoints to deliver the data to them in their desired format/protocol.  Customer C though, I'm struggling.

All of the samples I've seen in NService bus involve subscribing to a queue and firing an event when messages come in.  I think what I want to do here is when the customer makes the call for his data, I would grab all the messages on the queue for him and deliver them.

My question is, is this a proper application of NServiceBus or is this the wrong tool for the job?  If so, Are there any code samples out there that might show me how to handle customer C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question because it cuts right to the heart of how message-based systems--and specifically how NServiceBus--can solve a lot of pain.

You're definitely headed in the right direction for A and B--just subscribe to the appropriate message and then forward/push the data to your customer using the mechanism that they've chosen.  If they're offline, no big deal, the message-based system handles failures more gracefully than others.

Interestingly enough, customer C can be served in almost exactly the same way as A and B, but with a few extra steps.  To start, just setup another NSB endpoint that subscribes to the appropriate messages and then writes them out to persistent storage using the desired structure indicated by customer C.  You can write the messages out to a local database, to JSON files, or even to Amazon S3 blobs.  From there you just need to setup some kind of HTTP endpoint (not using NServiceBus) that allows the customer to query and retrieve the appropriate data.  If you're using S3 and giving out JSON blobs, you may not even need to setup an HTTP server--just let Amazon do all the work.

Another really cool side effect of this is that if future customers D and E decide they want to poll as well, but they need slightly different formats from each other and from customer C, you can accommodate them by setting up another handler that writes out files (or DB inserts) according to the format they dictate--all without changing how your system behaves.

Comment: I was worried that was going to be the answer, since it means adding some complexity with more storage, etc, but it will get the job done. With your proposed solution, would I also put NSB between the web service and the persistence (s3 in your example) or should I just build that in a "normal" synchronous fashion?

Comment: Whenever the customer queries directly for data, just give it to them in the easiest way possible and don't worry about adding NServiceBus into the mix.  Also, you may be adding "complexity" now, but you're really not--you're keeping things simple by keeping concerns separate.  This helps keep your architecture clean and expandable as you grow.

Comment: This maybe should be in a different question, but does it make more sense to have 1 queue, and then switch delivery mechanism based on the customer (data in the message), or is it better to have a separate queue for each customer?  I'm leaning toward the latter.

Comment: It would depend upon the SLA requirements for each customer.  If one had strict SLAs and was paying more for high availability and clustering, I would absolutely segregate queues.  Otherwise, it's just more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to expose an endpoint via WCF, but that is used for getting messages onto the bus.  If someone wants to poll a service, I would host that separately and let them manage when it gets called.